# Pulse Audio Configuration with Remote: Controlling Playback vs. Output Device

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I've gone through less than a dozen installations of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Xubuntu and Mint, all 15.10, and have noticed what seems to be a random selection of what the OS decides for the remote to control. Sometimes it's the application(s), usually Kodi, and other times its the Output Device and this is what I want.

I'm new to Linux and have done some reading about Lirc and Alsa but nothing popped out to answer my question. How can I select which device/app my MCE remote is controlling? How do I keep it from re-configuring itself if the system boots without it connected?